# Editing wp_options table in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, header, footer

I have a wordpress website hosted on godaddy. All pages on the website are having a header and a footer. The contents of the header and the footer are stored in the wp_options table in the option_value column in one row whose option_name is onelife-opts.

Whenever I try to edit the text in the option_value column of this row, the site stops displaying the header and the footer.

I am conversant with html and website designing and maintenence related activities.

In the wordpress admin panel, I am unable to search where to edit this header and footer content.

I would appreciate if any help I get in this regards.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

if you are editing this column value using double click of that column then please do not edit like this please go to edit entire row and save that value also one more advice to edit content in any editor and then replace those column value after that

Comment: Thanks. However, I always copy the text in a editor like notepad and then paste it back in the phpMyAdmin panel and save the record. The record gets saved, but then the page gets displayed without the header and footer, indicating that there is some problem with the edited content of the column in wp_options.

Comment: you have backup of that code before change anything?

Comment: Yes I have the backup on my local development pc

Comment: first replace this old option_value and check that you can visible header footer or not then you should carefully edit that column value

Comment: I have done just that. My site is running well right now. Just with old text in the header and unwanted matter in the footer. 

I am expecting guidance on how to safely edit this either in the database or from the wordpress admin panel.

Comment: it is better to edit from wordpress admin panel theme options or apperence->customization wherever settings are available

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same problem and it was driving me crazy experimenting with different text encodings and text editors etc.

Then I noticed that after copying/pasting the value from a backup, the length() of the option_value would change by a small amount. It turns out that on Windows the process of copying and pasting (even without editing) will convert LF line endings (unix) to CR/LF line endings.

This probably breaks because of the PHP object serialization format wordpress uses that relies on explicit lengths for strings. Inadvertently the strings are now a different length and so the deserialization in PHP falls over.

The only reliable solution I found if you're stuck using PhpMyAdmin on Windows to edit wp_options and you want/need to copy/paste is to strip out the CR characters after you've updated the option value:

```
update wp_options set option_value=REPLACE(option_value,char(13),'') where option_name = 'whatever'
```

You should be good to go.

P.S. I suppose it's always possible the option_value could be storing a legitimate (desired) CR character in a string for some reason in which case the above would remove it as well. I'd suggest it's highly unlikely but perhaps worth testing if you're concerned.